# Printed LaTeX PDF is missing ä, ü, ö, but has ß

Tags: pdf, printing

I just printed a PDF that I created with LaTeX on a Canon MX 340 that is connected via WLAN to my Kubuntu 14.04 machine. There it uses the *CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2* driver.

I use the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, ngerman, fleqn, DIV=15, headinclude, BCOR=2cm]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[charter, greekuppercase=italicized]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{berasans}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

In the result, the umlauts ä, ü and ö are missing. The letter ß is not missing, however. I have read that the characters like Ü can be represented as *u with " on top*. Then, I figure that the printer does not understand this. The result looks like this:

[image]

It should look like this (except the missing numbers, but that is a different story):

[image]

The source to this is:

```
Die Halbwertsbreiten der \SI{511}{\kilo\electronvolt}-Linie haben wir für den
linken Detektor auf \SI{<< fwhm_links[0][1] >>}{\kilo\electronvolt}, sowie auf
\SI{<< fwhm_rechts[0][1] >>}{\kilo\electronvolt} für den Rechten bestimmt.

Wir haben die Lebenszeit des $\frac 52^+$-Übergangs auf \SI{<< tau
>>}{\nano\second} bestimmen können. Der Literaturwert ist \SI{<< tau_lit
>>}{\nano\second} \parencite{gamma-133cs}. Somit ist unser Messergebnis etwas
mehr als eine Standardabweichung entfernt. Unser Fehler ist in der richtigen
Größenordnung abgeschätzt.
```

When I print it and force rasterization in the PDF viewer (Okular), I get all characters. So I just have to force rasterization every time, or is there a better way?

Comment: Unless it goes against any copyright issues, is there any way we could have you post part of the sample text from the content of the screenshot in your question above?

Comment: Of course. It is obvious which characters are missing if you know German, but as un-obvious as well if you do not. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, did you try to print it with Evince ? I just stumbled upon an issue when printing some documents with French accents ; they would disappear when printed from Okular (although visible on screen) but not from Evince. Just filed a bugreport for this.

Please contribute to it if it's related : https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=334692 :)

We'll change the bug name accordingly then and give more examples.